# Xpages And Select2

Tags: xpages, jquery-select2

I have installed plugin Bootstrap4XPages and then It works as i wanted it to be. but There is a huge problem. OnChange event does not trigger any function. I tried some suggestions but I could not be succeded. So is there any suggestion? How to trigger it.

```
    </xp:eventHandler>
    <xp:scriptBlock id="setLatencyBlock">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[XSP.addOnLoad(function() 
{ 
    XSP.attachPartial("view:_id1:FirmaAdi",null,"onclick", function(){}, 200, "view:_id1:divMain");
    x$("#{id:FirmaAdi}").select2().on("change", function(e) 
    {
        XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:FirmaAdi}",
        {
            onStart: function () { //alert("Started...")},
            onComplete: function () //{alert("Stopped...")}
        }); 
     }) 
});
]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
```

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28833461/785061

Comment: What release of Domino are you running?  Just asking because for many releases/years now the Bootstrap3 theme has been available natively in Domino, replacing the need to install the Bootstrap4Xpages plugin which I believe is outdated now.

Comment: I have DOmino V10 installed on Server. And then I have already installed Bootstrap4Xpages on to Domino Server and Domino Designer.  What i wanted to do is just a searchable combobox. I have more than 1000 company names. So İ want to use a searchable combobox then the  user can easly find the company in Combobox... So the best way I could find so far is the select2...

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the xe:djComboBox should work for you right out of the V10 box without the need to add any dated plugin.  If you do need bootstrap  simply implement the bootstrap3 theme also available natively in V10.  See my answer below and kindly vote up if it works for you

Comment: The problem is that select2 is needed mainly for large lists, where there is a limitation on dblookup (or Dbcolumn). How can this large list be completed? And everyone would also like to use lazy loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lame workaround, but the way I fix this is by creating a standard XPages combobox   and a button that handles the onchange. Here's an example:

```
        <xp:comboBox id="fldSelection" value="#{viewScope.fldSelect}" styleClass="select2_fldSelect">
            <xp:this.attrs>
                <xp:attr name="name" value="fldSelect">
                </xp:attr>
            </xp:this.attrs>

            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Item 1"></xp:selectItem>
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Item 2"></xp:selectItem>
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Item 3"></xp:selectItem>
        </xp:comboBox>

        <xp:button value="RefreshWF" id="btnRefresh_fldSelect" style="display:none;">

            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[alert("Changed.");]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
        <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[var fldWorkflowId = $(".select2_fldSelect");
        fldWorkflowId.select2({
                    placeholder: fldWorkflowId.attr("title"),
                    allowClear: true, 
                    dropdownCssClass: "noFilter2"
                }); 

        fldWorkflowId.change(function(e){
        var btnRefresh = document.getElementById("#{id:btnRefresh_fldSelect}");
        if(btnRefresh) btnRefresh.click();
        })

        ]]>    </xp:this.value>
        </xp:scriptBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap support, I recommend uninstalling very old Bootstrap4Xpages plugin off Domino and Designer and then switching to the Bootstrap3 theme in the Xsp Properties for your application.  That is all you need to enable the Bootstrap3 support that is native to V10.

For the filtering select function, add the Dojo Combo Box function from the Dojo Forms section in the Controls pallete. Note that you don't need either Bootstrap implementation to use this control.

```
<xe:djComboBox id="Company1" value="#{document1.Company}">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue=""></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@DbColumn(@DbName(),"CompaniesByName",1)}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
</xe:djComboBox>
```